# (PHP beginner) Can I use loop to assign variable ordinal number suffix?

Tags: php

I want to assign variable name $filename1, $filename2, $filename3
so I write code like this

```
for ($i=1; $i <= 3; $i++) { 
$filename.$i = 'images/location/'.$i;
}
```

but It error.

Now I use array to fix problem. But anyway I still wonder, is it possible to assign variable name with ordinal number suffix by using loop?

```
$filename = array();
for ($i=1; $i <= 3; $i++) { 
$filename[] = 'images/location/'.$i;
}
```

Comment: an array is in most cases is the better option anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

e.g.

```
$i = 1;

${'filename' . $i} = 'apple';

echo $filename1; // prints apple
```

Answer (score 0):

You CAN pass a variable as a variable name. The way to do so is with `$$`.

In your case, I would assign the variable name by concatenating the desired string, and then assign the variable in a separate line.

```
$filename = "filename" . $i;
$$filename = 'images/location/'.$i;
```